# How to import resource that has parenthesis in the resource id?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to import this existing Azure SQL Analytics solution with the resource ID of:

/subscriptions/abcfe54c-ae03-45f1-b2e2-d37f04b2fdef/resourcegroups/e1us-dev-rg-01/providers/Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/AzureSQLAnalytics(cts-e1us-dev-la-01)

using

```
terraform import azurerm_log_analytics_solution.solution[\`"e1us\`"] /subscriptions/abcfe54c-ae03-45f1-b2e2-d37f04b2fdef/resourcegroups/e1us-dev-rg-01/providers/Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/AzureSQLAnalytics(cts-e1us-dev-la-01)
```

and I am getting the following output:

```
cts-e1us-dev-la-01: The term 'cts-e1us-dev-la-01' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

How should I handle that last part within the parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the parenthesis

e.g.

```
terraform import azurerm_log_analytics_solution.solution[\`"e1us\`"] /subscriptions/abcfe54c-ae03-45f1-b2e2-d37f04b2fdef/resourcegroups/e1us-dev-rg-01/providers/Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/AzureSQLAnalytics\(cts-e1us-dev-la-01\)
```

or wrapping it with quotes

```
terraform import azurerm_log_analytics_solution.solution[\`"e1us\`"] "/subscriptions/abcfe54c-ae03-45f1-b2e2-d37f04b2fdef/resourcegroups/e1us-dev-rg-01/providers/Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/AzureSQLAnalytics(cts-e1us-dev-la-01)"
```

Sounds like the shell is trying to open up a sub-shell.